# Android: Problem with listView and getView-Method

Tags: java, android, listview, getview

Hey guys I am pretty new to android programming and I have a few questions. I hope somebody can help.

I am using the code:

```
new ArrayAdapter<Customer> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,emptyListForInitialization) {...
```

But I want to use my own layout I created `("R.layout.custom_customer_layout")`.

I can use it, if I CHANGE the code-line with:

```
new ArrayAdapter<Customer> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,emptyListForInitialization)
```

with my layout `("R.layout.custom_customer_layout")`

AND REMOVE THE CODE

```
View view =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

And UNCOMMENT the section (code between /* ... */ ) below it.

---

But I don't get the getView-Method.

WHY DO I HAVE TO REFER TWICE TO MY LAYOUT?

First time during creating the new ArrayList

Second time in the getView-Method???

---

This is the important part of my code:

```
    private ListView myTestListView;

    private void initializeCustomerListView() {
        myTestListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_customers);

        List<Customer> emptyListForInitialization = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayAdapter<Customer> customerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Customer> (
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                emptyListForInitialization) {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                /*
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_customer_layout,null);

                TextView textViewName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView20);
                TextView textViewContact = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView21);
                TextView textViewMobile = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView25);

                textViewName.setText(this.getItem(position).getCustomerName());
                textViewContact.setText(this.getItem(position).getCounterpart());
                textViewMobile.setText(this.getItem(position).getMobilePhoneNumber());
                */
                return view;
            }
        };

        myTestListView.setAdapter(customerArrayAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: One question per post, please. If you would, pick one that you would like addressed here, and remove the others. You can create new questions for those, if needed.

Comment: Okay sorry - now it's done!